# ionic2 login through facebook not working

Tags: android, oauth, ionic2

as i was trying to log into my app using facebook on ionic2 but when i used that code it is showing error that " Cannot find name 'facebookConnectPlugin'." as i have already installed cordova plugin

```
login() {
    facebookConnectPlugin.login(['email'], function(response) {
        alert('Logged in');
        alert(JSON.stringify(response.authResponse));
    }, function(error){
        alert(error);
    })
}

getdetails() {
    facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus((response) => {
        if(response.status == "connected") {
            facebookConnectPlugin.api('/' + response.authResponse.userID + '?fields=id,name,gender',[], 
            function onSuccess(result) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(result));
            },
            function onError(error) {
                alert(error);
            }
            );
        }
        else {
            alert('Not logged in');
        }
    })
}

logout() {
    facebookConnectPlugin.logout((response) => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    })
}
```

then i found another solution which is

```
fblogin(){
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  Facebook.login(["email"]).then((result) => {
    console.log(result)
   })
})
```

}

it is also showing an error that : "Property 'platform' does not exist on type 'HomePage'."

i am running that code using "ionic run android" and my device is connected and other application running normally.

Comment: have you imported `platform` from `ionic-angular` and injected in constructor? Also you need to declare plugin global object `declare facebookConnectPlugin:any`

Comment: while importing platform it is showing:-
Module '"/Users/cronj/Desktop/projects/slotuin/facebookAuthentication/node_modules/ionic-angular/index"' has
            no exported member 'platform'.

and other thing if i declare    facebookConnectPlugin : any it will work as an local member of class and i have to use all facebookConnectPlugin with "this" and it is not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [the docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/Platform/).

Do

```
import {Platform} from 'ionic-angular`;
```

Also declare cordova plugins globally immediately after import statements and before the class is defined.

```
//import statements.

declare var facebookConnectPlugin:any;

@Component()
//...
```

Comment: thanks for that response....it worked...but a with a little change...
    declare facebookConnectPlugin:any
replaced with declare var facebookConnectPlugin